# Android: How to create 2d animations

Tags: java, android, animation, android-studio, 2d

I'm in the middle of my first android project, I'm trying to create my own animations to implement into simple things like button's onClick's. Can I create the animations in tools like After Effects and such and somehow import them into Android studio, or do I have to create them through java and xml?
This example is just a mock up but it's the kind of animations I'm aiming for. 
https://dribbble.com/shots/2607005-Low-Fidelity-Filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not import animations from After Effects directly into Android Studio, so you'll have to define your animations via code.

I would suggest reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) link to understand how android animations work and how to implement them.

For simple animations (alpha, rotate, translate, scale) you can use the [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) by calling `animate()` on a view, for example:

```
 myView.animate().alpha(0);
```